# Cancel all running workflows on a list

Tags: 2007, workflow

Without access to the server, is there a way to cancel all workflow instances currently running on a given list (without removing the workflow itself)?

I am looking for a solution that works in SP 2007.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're going down the code option, you could have code which gets a collection of all the running workflows, and iterates through them and cancels them one at a time, using code like this post:

[How to cancel a workflow programmatically](http://blog.brianfarnhill.com/2008/10/how-to-cancel-a-workflow-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

You could go to list settings and remove the workflow association completely.

Comment: Paul, I have edited my question. My purpose is actually to cancel the running instances, but not delete the workflow. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem... in that case, without using a code solution, I think your only option would be to terminate each workflow instance one-by-one.

Answer (score 0):

Is the workflow an approval workflow? Usually deleting all the approval tasks from the task list cancels all the workflows. Each workflow instance will get a workflow cancelled event too, which is a rejected status i think.